# How can I configure Google Chrome so that website notifications are blocked by default?

Tags: google-chrome

Each time a website wants me to see its notifications I get this message:

[image]

How can I configure Google Chrome so that website notifications are blocked by default?

Answer (score 1):

In chrome://settings, `Privacy` section, open `Content settings`, then scroll down to:

[image]